# Moved CodeIgniter Application to a different folder, I can't access any of the controllers

Tags: codeigniter

I have an application that was in a folder named "project", I moved all the files from "project" into "project/admin", because I decided it was a better structure, to access the application via the www.example.com/project/admin URL.

The problem I am facing now is that I cannot access any of the controllers. The index page, which is set to show a certain page from a controller works fine, but the link doesn't work.

To make myself clear, here is an example:

Let's say I have a controller called "manage" which contains a function named "list_products". If I set the variable `$route['default_controller'] = "manage/list_products"` the index page ( www.example.com/project/admin ) loads perfectly. But if I try to access the URL `www.example.com/project/admin/manage/list_products` I get a 404. None of my pages load except for the index.php.

I have changed my base_url to the new folder but I don't know if I have to change anything else in the config.

I hope someone can help with this,
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you edit the `.htaccess` file? you should adjust `RewriteBase` configuration.

Comment: I had to rewrite the .htaccess to remove the index.php.

Answer (score 1):

The default controller would not be set up as you describe.  You should not have the function name in the default controller variable.  It should be:

```
$route['default_controller'] = "manage";
```